# iOS XCode - Possible to hide OTHER Apps From SpringBoard?

Tags: ios, xcode, springboard

I know it's possible to add a key to my plist to hide my OWN app on the iOS SpringBoard, but is it possible to hide other apps?

I heard about an app that allowed parents to lock apps for their kids at specific times (no late-night Facebooking, etc) and wondering how they'd do this?

Comment: These apps use an MDM server to push profiles to the device.  You cannot hide apps directly from your app.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible from a normal third party app.